# How can I raise exception in model while rendering the template?

Tags: django, django-models

I have some custom functions in model class which process some data, and then add custom attribute to the model. Thing is, I do not know how could I raise an exception if there are any while the template is generated (the error seems to be only silent, so it will process the template further but gives NO ERROR )
In the view

```
test.objects.all()
render_to_string('template.html', {'test': test})
```

In the template

```
{{ entry.state }}
```

In the model:

```
@property
def state(self):
    somedict = {'a': 111}
    try:
       print somedict['b']
    except Exception as e:
       FATAL_ERROR
```

What should I put in the place of fatal_error so that the template processing should stop immediatelly, or gives some exception to the render function ? 
Thanks

Comment: can you just use `somedict.get('b', None)` instead of raising errors?

Comment: Usage of dictionary was kind of example. The exception can be everything, I am fetching the state attribute from remote server, and if case there is some problem with connection, I cannot let it know to my view.

Comment: Are you using any particular library for the remote requests or is it a custom solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/):

> If the variable raises an exception when called, the exception will be propagated, unless the exception has an `attribute silent_variable_failure` whose value is `True`. If the exception does have a `silent_variable_failure` attribute whose value is `True`, the variable will render as an empty string.

And the example:

```
t = Template("My name is {{ person.first_name }}.")
class PersonClass3:
    def first_name(self):
        raise AssertionError("foo")
p = PersonClass3()
t.render(Context({"person": p}))
#Error raised


class SilentAssertionError(Exception):
    silent_variable_failure = True

class PersonClass4:
    def first_name(self):
        raise SilentAssertionError
p = PersonClass4()
t.render(Context({"person": p}))
"My name is ."
#No error raised
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. - `If the variable raises an exception when called, the exception will be propagated, unless the exception has an attribute silent_variable_failure whose value is True.`

Answer (score 0):

You can set `TEMPLATE_DEBUG` to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

I got a problem similar to yours.
But the issue that make me getting confused is that why exception does not raise at all when i
didn't catch it.

It seems that it just happened when touching model instance(eg. getattr(model, not_exists_attribute)).